# MrBayes 3.2.6 Linux Arrow keys not working

Tags: linux, terminal

Not sure this is the best place to ask for this, but since the other MrBayes questions were also posted here, I'll give it a try.

So I'm trying to run MrBayes on Arch Linux (4.4.1-2-ARCH) and the program works fine but the arrow keys don't work.

The output for the arrow keys looks like this:

```
MrBayes > ^[[A^[[C^[[B^[[D
```

In the terminal (xterm etc.) the arrow keys work just fine.

Googling this turned up nothing... Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this behaviour, installing rlwrap does the trick.
rlwrap will convert the escape characters to their corresponding actions and also provides a history. Sadly though no tab-completion for directories.

For linux execute MrBayes like this:

```
$ rlwrap mb
```

or for mpi version:

```
$ rlwrap mpirun -np x mb
```

where x is number of processors/threads used.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow keys on almost all terminals send escape sequences.  If a program handles arrow keys, it does this by noticing that an escape character is read, and follows up by looking for the rest of the escape sequence.

A program that does *not* expect escape sequences would generally be using the default terminal I/O modes, in which the operating system's terminal driver conventionally echoes an escape character as `^[` (because on most keyboards you can type an escape character that way).

From your description, it sounds as if [MyBayes](http://mrbayes.sourceforge.net/manual.php) does not expect escape sequences.

Rather than using arrow keys for command-line editing, you should be able to use the backspace or delete (*erase*) character which the terminal sends.